# How to convert FTP server to secure SFTP on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, sftp

I have FTP server on Amazon EC2 which I can access by giving this URL: `ftp.websitename.com:4522`
after that username and password to accessing the files from this location.

Now I want to convert into secure FTP like if I will give `sftp.websitename.com:4522` then it will ask me for username and password and allow me to login into the application.

First of all is this possible?

I tried below instructions for installing [vsftd1](http://linuxadminzone.com/install-and-configure-ftp-server-in-amazon-ec2-instance/) [vsftd2](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Configuring_vsftpd_for_secure_connections_(TLS/SSL/SFTP)) but didn't help me.

after doing the changes into this two link I tried to login through WinSCP and selected file protocol as SFTP and typed `ftp.websitename.com`, in port number 4522 and given username and password but didn't allowed me to log in.

edit 1 :

i have my amazon ec2 instance in centos 64bit.
someone else set-up the ftp connection and now i am taking forward from that point,i will get all the details and will try to modify my question in more specific way.

Comment: Did mix up ftps and sftp. ftps is FTP extended with TLS while sftp is file transfer over SSH, which is a completely different protocol, uses other ports etc. Some clients can do sftp and ftps, but an FTP server can usually not do sftp but only ftps.

Answer (score 0):

*You didn't specify, what OS are you running. But from a reference to vsftpd, I assume some *nix flavor. You didn't specify, what FTP server you have running, and how did you set it up. Your question is pretty vague. But I'll try to give some hints.*

The vsftpd is an FTP server only. It does not support the SFTP. It supports the FTPS (FTP over TLS) though. *Do not get confused by its name. While the vsftpd stands for "very secure FTP daemon", it just means, it aims to implement FTP securely, not that it implements the SFTP"*.

Note that virtually all *nix servers come with an SSH/SFTP server built-in (OpenSSH). It runs on port 22.
For instructions how to connect to the EC2 SFTP server with WinSCP, see (my) guide:
[Connecting Securely to Amazon EC2 Server with SFTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2).

Also make sure you understand the difference between the SFTP and the FTPS.

Comment: thanks martin for the answer i have edited my question, once i will get all the details i will try to modify more specific question so that i can get my answer.